# Id to separate inputs and PDO

Tags: php, pdo

I have those buttons below, each of them had different functions, the first is to update user situation e the second is to approve user. Both works, but the issue is that they are executed at the same time. I'm new in PDO , and i'm having difficulties to work with `ids` and how to get a `id` information to separate those two things, can somebody give some tips?? Thank you very much!

```
        <center><button type="submit" id="btn_login" class="btn btn-primary" name="mudar">Update</button>
      <?php 
        if (input::exists()) {
          $validate = new validate();
          $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
            'id1' => array('required' => true),
            'grupos' => array('required' => true)
          ));            
          if ($validation->passed()) {

            try{
                $user->update('dados', 'idvoluntario', input::get('id1'), array('grupo' => input::get('grupos')));
            }catch(Exception $e){
              die($e->getMessage());
            }
          }
        }
      ?> 
    </center>
```

And the second:

```
        <center><button type="submit" id="btn_login1" class="btn btn-primary" name="aprovar">Aprove</button>
      <?php 
        if (input::exists()) {
          $validate = new validate();
          $validation = $validate->check($_POST, array(
            'id' => array('required' => true),
            'grupos' => array('required' => true)
          ));            
          if ($validation->passed()) {

            try{
                $user->update('dados', 'idvoluntario', input::get('id'), array('aprovado' => 'sim'));
            }catch(Exception $e){
              die($e->getMessage());
            }
          }
        }
      ?> 
    </center>
```

Comment: have you surrounded the inputs in a form? If so whats the result of input::exists?

Comment: @Juakali92 Yep, each of them are surrounded in a form. For example, when i only  want to update the situation, it isn't possible because the two input::exists returns true!

Comment: Where does the `input` class come from?

Comment: @Barmar The `input` class come from another php file.

Answer (score -1):

You need to check which button was used to submit the form:

```
if (isset($_POST['mudar'])) {
    // process the first button
} elseif (isset($_POST['aprovar'])) {
    // process the second button
}
```

I don't know how your `input` class works, but maybe you can do `input::exists('mudar'))` instead of using `isset()`.

Comment: i think the static function input exists is searching through all $_post input. Probably needs to pass through the 'murdar' as a param.

Comment: But it's not checking for specific inputs, so it doesn't distinguish between the two submissions.

Comment: i updated before you responded. As said if he passes through the params on his buttons it should resolve.

Comment: It works just fine. My mistake were that i was trying to check using the form id, i forgot about the button. Thank you so much, it helps a lot!